# NSTask code, using objectivec, to get command line output no longer working in El Capitan

Tags: objective-c, osx-elcapitan

The following code previously worked fine in OS X Yosemite, but now it usually does not work in OS X El Capitan, usually returning an empty string, for output.

```
- (NSString*)runCommandLine:(NSString*)executable withArgs:(NSString*)arg {
    NSTask *commandLine = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [commandLine setLaunchPath: executable];
    NSLog(@"CL EXECUTABLE: %@",executable);

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: arg, nil];
    [commandLine setArguments: arguments];
    NSLog(@"CL ARGUMENTS: %@",arguments);

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [commandLine setStandardOutput: pipe];  
    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];    
    [commandLine launch];
    [commandLine waitUntilExit];

    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"CL OUTPUT: %@",output);
    return output;
}
```

I then call it using the following example. There is no error, output is simple "" and the terminationstatus is 1:

```
NSString *adbLocation = [self runCommandLine:@"/usr/bin/which" withArgs: @"adb"];
```

This example for ls works fine (termination status is 0).

```
NSString *lsOutput = [[self runCommandLine:@"/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls" withArgs: @"-la"];
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Comment: Add a standard error pipe, check `terminationStatus`

Comment: Aside from your problem, `NSUserName()` returns the short user name of the current user, a shell call is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ken for sending me in the right direction.

I solved this by doing:
`NSString *executable = @"/bin/bash"`

And for my example case of `which adb`:

`NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-l",@"-c",@"which adb",nil];`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> NSString *whoamiOutput = [self runCommandLine:@"/usr/bin/whoami" withArgs: @""];
> ```

The above does *not* correspond to the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/whoami
```

It corresponds to this:

```
$ /usr/bin/whoami ""
```

For me, on Yosemite, this writes a usage message to standard error (not standard output) and exits with status 1. So, that exactly corresponds to what you're seeing.

You need a way to specify no arguments. Given the code you use to set the `arguments` property of the task, you can just pass `nil` instead of the empty string you're currently passing.

(Of course, as vadian points out in comments, this is a ridiculous thing to do in a real app. Hopefully, this is just an example for illustration purposes.)

Comment: And? 0 means success. What does `which adb` show in a shell in a Terminal window?

Comment: Edit: Thanks Ken, it was simply an example, and passing nil indeed fixes the whoami case, however what I am really trying to do is: NSString *adbLocation = [self runCommandLine:@"/usr/bin/which" withArgs: @"adb"]; Unfortunately this is also returning a terminationstatus of 1, output of "".

When using Terminal, `which adb` returns the path to ADB, just as I would expect, just as it did with Yosemite

Comment: And what is the path to `adb`. I don't have such a command here on my Yosemite system. If it's not in a standard directory, then the issue is probably that your program doesn't have the same PATH in its environment as your shell does.